# Reset Random Initialization on Pytorch

Tags: random, neural-network, pytorch

I want to do some experiments on feedforward neural networks. To make a fair comparison, I need them to have the exact same random initialisation. How can I do it?

Is there a way to save the same initial weights such that I can train a network and then reinitialize it exactly as it was before?

I have been trying to save the initial parameters on a list, called 'init' , and then reassign the parameters  but it did not work:

`i = 0
for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    param = init[i]
    i += 1`

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try seeding random via:

```
torch.manual_seed(seed)
torch.manual_seed_all(seed)
```

Note you have to seed random before each model initialisation. If this doesn't work, try the following:

```
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
```